# If $\Sigma^{-1}=(A^{-1})^TA^{-1}$, then why does $|A^{-1}|=|\Sigma|^{-1/2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, linear-transformations, normal-distribution, transformation

In the derivation of the joint pdf of $f_\textbf{X}(\pmb{x})$, where $\textbf{X}=\pmb\mu+A\pmb Z$ and $\textbf{X}\sim~N_n(\pmb\mu,\Sigma)$, there is a step I do not understand.

In particular, it is the fact that if $\Sigma^{-1}=(A^{-1})^TA^{-1}$, then $|A^{-1}|=|\Sigma|^{-1/2}$. This shows up during the derivation of the joint pdf as follows:

$$f_{\textbf{X}}(\textbf{x})=|A^{-1}|(2\pi)^{-n/2}exp\bigg(-\frac{1}{2} (\pmb x-\pmb \mu)^T(A^{-1})^TA^{-1}(\pmb x-\pmb \mu)\bigg) $$

Now since $\Sigma=AA^T$ is invertible we have $\Sigma^{-1}=(AA^T)^{-1}=(A^T)^{-1}A^{-1}=(A^{-1})^TA^{-1}$ and thus,

$$f_{\textbf{X}}(\textbf{x})=(2\pi)^{-n/2}|\Sigma|^{-1/2}exp\bigg(-\frac{1}{2} (\pmb x-\pmb \mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\pmb x-\pmb \mu)\bigg) $$

I can't understand how $|\Sigma|^{-1/2}=|A^{-1}|$?

Comment: Please insert the definition of $|B|$ for a given matrix $B$...

Comment: That's what you get taking determinant of both sides.

Comment: Hint: a matrix and its transpose have the same determinant

Comment: I guess $A$ is square matrix, then $|\Sigma|^{-1/2}=|A^{-1}|$ follows from $|A|=|A^T|$

Comment: @DavidReed Oh... Thanks, that clarifies my problem!

Comment: Although if we have $|\Sigma^{-1}|=|(A^{-1})^TA^{-1}|=|A^{-1}|^2$, then why isn't it $|\Sigma^{-1}|^{1/2}=|A^{-1}|$, rather than $|\Sigma|^{-1/2}=|A^{-1}|$?

Comment: It's also a theorem that $|A^{-1}| = |A|^{-1} $. This is actually easy enough to prove in a comment: $1 = |I| = |A^{-1}A| = |A^{-1}||A| \to |A^{-1}| = |A|^{-1}  $

Comment: @DavidReed Bravo!